# Scrapy - decorator for responses, can it access data 'inside' the method?

Tags: python, scrapy

Using scrapy. We have a `decorator for logging Scrapy responses` in `utils/__init__.py` and it prints what it finds, this is OK. Only we woule also like to know "how many links it found on the page". So as a result we have 2 log statements, resulting in 2 lines:

- 200: page found XXX
- Found 23 products on category page XXX

Instead we would like to have 1 log statement, preferably somewhere central and not in every crawler (we have a lot! that prints

- 200: Page found, with # products - XXX

I dont think the `log_response` is able to access data 'inside' the method because that occurs later? Or is there a way to achieve this where we have 1 central method like `log_response` but that can also access the # links found so we can remove all the `Found 23 products on category page XXX` in individual crawlers.

**Question**: how can we centralize this and make it more generic so ther is no logc in the crawler class, but somewhere else / more central?

```
# decorator for logging Scrapy responses
def log_response(title, with_meta=False):
    def real_decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(self, response):
            if not with_meta:
                path = urlparse(response.url).path.strip('/')
                self.logger.info(f'200 {title}: {path}')
```

this is how we report the # links found in the comment

```
@log_response('category')
def parse_category(self, response):
    product_links = response.xpath('//a[@class="mainLink"]/@href').getall()
    self.logger.info(f'Found {len(product_links)} products on category page  (url {response.url}))')
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably doing your logging in a SpiderMiddleware's [`process_spider_output`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.SpiderMiddleware.process_spider_output) method, since it will be called every time a spider callback finishes.

Simply iterate over `result`, count the items, and make a logging call once your loop is over.

```py
class LoggingMiddleware:
    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        count = 0
        for x in result:
            yield x
            # I think this is a sufficient check?
            if not isinstance(x, scrapy.Request):
                count += 1
        spider.logger.info(f'{response.status}: Page found, with {count} products - {response.url}')
```

Comment: thx. so the method is not the items method but rather a higher hierarchy level (i.e. the category). We run the category_parse method that crawls all categories, then reads all href links found in product_links ... after this the product_links are visited 1 by 1 and the results in an item() object that is yielded

How would we apply the above to only `category_parse ` (and not every item product) and in addition how can the process_spider_output access the product_links list containing the # products (pages) to visit

Comment: There's no way to access the variable inside the method, but that shouldn't be a problem. If I understand correctly, you want to count requests instead of items. That should be doable by just removing that `not`  on line 7. You might need to come up with a way of identifying the output of your category method though...